# nodejs/express and binary data in POST

Tags: node.js, express, binary

I'm trying to send binary data to an express app. It works fine, as long as my values are smaller than 0x80.  If a single value is 0x80 or greater, it messes up the whole buffer.

Express Handler:

```
binary = require('binary');

exports.api = function(req, res){
    var body = req.body.name;
    var buf = new Buffer(body,'binary');

    console.log('body',req.body);
    console.log('req body len', body.length);
    console.log('buf len', buf.length);

    var g = binary.parse(buf)
        .word16bu('a') // unsigned 16-bit big-endian value
        .word16bu('b').vars

    console.log('g.a', g.a);
    console.log('g.b', g.b);

  res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

Python client (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
import requests
from struct import pack
# send two unsigned shorts (16-bits each).
requests.post('http://localhost:3000/api', data={'name':pack('!HH',1,2)})
```

Express output when data = 1,2.  **This is what I'd expect**.

```
body { name: '\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0002' }
req body len 4
buf len 4
g.a 1
g.b 2
POST /api 200 1ms - 23b
```

Express output when data = 1,0xFF.  It's interesting to note that 9520 is actually 0x25 0x30 in hex, which corresponds to "%0" in ASCII.  Yes, it appears to be parsing the '%00%01...' string.  **I wish I knew how to prevent this!!!**

```
body { name: '%00%01%00%FF' }
req body len 12
buf len 12
g.a 9520
g.b 12325
POST /api 200 2ms - 23b
```

Comment: how to upload binary files using multer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8COHTGz2cc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out to be an encoding issue.  Everything seems to default to 'utf8', but in this case it needs to be set to 'binary'.

For example:

```
var buf = new Buffer(body.toString('binary'),'binary');
```

Equally as important, I needed to set nodejs multiparty parser's encoding to 'binary'.  See: https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty/issues/37

Comment: I get the error "req.body.toString is not a function", even though I'm declaring `body` the same way as you. Do you know where this could come from?

Answer (score 9):

After struggling with this for way too long, I came up with this solution:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream', limit : '2mb'}))

app.post('/nist-ws/rest/v1/nist/', function(req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'nist_received', `/${Date.now()}.nist`)
    fs.open(filePath, 'w', function(err, fd) {  
        fs.write(fd, req.body, 0, req.body.length, null, function(err) {
            if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
            fs.close(fd, function() {
                console.log('wrote the file successfully');
                res.status(200).end();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

bodyParser.raw fills req.body with a Buffer and the rest of the code is from: https://stackabuse.com/writing-to-files-in-node-js/

Comment: To add to Carl's answer.  This didn't work for me when receiving files via a form.  To fix that I changed his `bodyParser.raw` line to:
`app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'multipart/form-data', limit : '2mb'}))`

Because that's the `Content-Type` when sending forms.

Answer (score 2):

A modern Typescript safe way would probably look like this:

```js
export async function readBodyAsBuffer(req: any): Promise<Buffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(0)
    req.setEncoding(null)
    req.on(
      "data",
      (chunk: string) => (buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, Buffer.from(chunk)]))
    )
    req.on("end", () => resolve(buffer))
    req.on("error", reject)
  })
}
```

You can now simply get the body as Buffer like this:

```js
let buffer = await readBodyAsBuffer(req)
```

Comment: `Buffer.concat` used like this has horrid performance for large files. You'd be happier to collect the data chunks into an Array and do the `Buffer.concat` only once on the array at "end".

Comment: That's a great hint. I agree, that would very likely improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Holtwick, here's what I'm using:

```
const readBodyAsBuffer = (req: express.Request): Promise<Buffer> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body: Buffer[] = []
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      body.push(chunk)
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(body))
    })
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Use as `const buffer = await readBodyAsBuffer(req)`