# How can I make this request in nodejs(status 415)?

Tags: node.js, bash, curl, request, node-request

I was using bash to do a task. And had some mess while trying to parse the response. Now I am using nodejs for the task. But I get following error:

```
"httpStatus" : 415,
"messages" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "305",
    "message" : "Unsupported media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
} ]
```

This used to be my curl request in bash file:

```
 curl --include\                      
     --request POST \                 
     --user "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" \           
     --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.profitbricks.resource+json" \ 
     --data-binary "{             
         \"properties\": {           
             \"name\": \"$servername\",      
             \"ram\": $RAM,
             \"cores\": $CORES     
         }  
     }" \                      
     https://api.profitbricks.com/rest/datacenters/$ID/servers ;
```

This is my current request:

```
var request = require('request');
var reqoptions = {                 
  method: 'POST',             
  uri: 'https://api.profitbricks.com/rest/datacenters/'+options.vdcID+'/servers',
  form:{
     "properties":{
        "cores": options.cores,
        "ram": options.ramsize,
        "name": options.servername 
     }
  },
  headers: {               
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(options.user+':'+options.password).toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.profitbricks.resource+json'
   }
};   

request(reqoptions, function(err, res, body){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was serialization. I stringified the object. Now it works.

```
var request = require('request');
var body = {
     "properties":{
        "cores": options.cores,
        "ram": options.ramsize,
        "name": options.servername 
     }
  }
var reqoptions = {                 
  method: 'POST',             
  uri: 'https://api.profitbricks.com/rest/datacenters/'+options.vdcID+'/servers',
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {               
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(options.user+':'+options.password).toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.profitbricks.resource+json'
   }
};   

request(reqoptions, function(err, res, body){});
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`form` option changing content-type to `form-urlencoded`

you shouldn't use `form` in request options

send a binary data like here [nodejs/express and binary data in POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503393/nodejs-express-and-binary-data-in-post)

so use `body: myBuffer` instead of `form: {...}`

Comment: i tried some variation, dint work. could you show a little code please?

Comment: damn, a simple stringify did the trick. I dint serialize the object.